# What ways are there to get the user's logon name via the Win32 API?

Tags: winapi

I know three ways for getting the logon name of the current user in Windows using the Win32 API:

- [GetUserNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamea) / [GetUserNameW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamew)
- [GetUserNameExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-getusernameexa) / [GetUserNameExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-getusernameexw)
- [GetEnvironmentVariableA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getenvironmentvariablea) / [GetEnvironmentVariableW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getenvironmentvariablew) reading %USERNAME%

Are there any others?

Comment: [`WTSQuerySessionInformation(A|W)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw) querying for `WTSUserName`

Comment: what sense in question ? for what you try get this?

Comment: *detects the user name wrongly in a specific environment* - and what name returned vs correct name ? are this name of another user/built in account ? are for instance used impersonation here, etc ? need more info if you want help in research this

Comment: @RbMm I don't want help to research this, I simply want answer(s) to the question I asked. Just assume I had answered "out of curiosity only" in my first comment.

Comment: @dummzeuch - exist many different ways and it combinations (not single api call, but several calls). i be say need more info for research your problem (which you not want)